# Is something missing from my Macbook Air package?

Tags: macbook-pro

Should my brand new Macbook Air 13'' have come with a CD/DVD in that black booklet included in the package?

Comment: What do plan on doing with a CD and your MacBook Air?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Apple is ditching optical media, even when the computer has an optical drive.

Answer (score 9):

No. The mid 2011 air uses Internet recovery to network boot and reinstall lion.

You can use the recovery hd assistant to make your own USB media for booting if you don't expect to have Internet when you ever need to restore your air.

Comment: What happened to the little USB drives that came with MacBook Airs in 2010? I have the 2010 MacBook Air so I don't know, but I thought they would still give you a reinstall USB drive for Lion?

Comment: Those shipped for a very short window. Most macs now ship with no media and just Internet recovery if you don't make your own recovery hd on a USB drive.